# multiple mongodb transactions over a single session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

I'm using mongodb in an enterprise application and for some use cases, I have to use transactions.

It seems like at first I wasn't using mongodb's `ClientSession`s correctly. Each time I was trying to start a transaction, I would also start a session but this turned out to be a mistake. At one point when I was testing the app with multiple concurrent requests, I got `WriteConflict` errors which apparently means I was executing concurrent transactions on a single collection on two separate sessions.

So now it seems that for each tenant of our app, I need to have a pre-created session and any time I want to execute a transaction, I just use that existing session. But it seems like there can only be one active transaction on a session, which means I need to also maintain a queue for my transactions so that I can execute the next transaction as soon as the previous transaction is done and the session is free. But this will make some parts of the app really slow.

So my question is, is there any alternative to this approach so that I can use transactions but also be able to respond to requests concurrently so that I don't get a performance penalty?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The WriteConflict error isn't about the number of sessions, it's about multiple things trying to update the same document at the same time.

In a transaction, the data modifications are staged, and then applied all at once when the transaction is committed.  If one of the documents that is going to be modified by a transaction has changed, the transaction code can't be sure if you intended that modification to be include in or overwritten by the transaction, so it throws the WriteConflict so that your application code can decide how to handle that.  This is why the WriteConflict error include the text 'Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.'

If you have multiple transactions all trying to modify the same document, like a counter, they will have to take turns.